# iOS 11 Searchcontroller jumps top of screen

Tags: ios, uisearchcontroller

having the same issue as already posted (non of the answers works..), my table is a fixed width, and in iOS 10.x the searchbar (which is in the tableviewheader), stays the same size when typing. However in iOS 11, it jumps to the top of the screen and gets stretched out over the total width. All options tried;

```
self.definesPresentationContext  = YES; 
tableHeaderView.clipsToBounds = YES; 
etc
```

but nothing seems to change.. it still jumps to the top full width..

Any other options?

Xcode 9 GM with iOS 11 (Xcode 9 GM with iOS 10.x and it all works fine)

Answer (score 1):

First you need to add UISearchControllerDelegate

then set your delegate

```
self.searchController.delegate=self;
```

Place a new view which will hold your searchController

```
-(void) viewDidLoad{
    UIView *searchContainerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.searchTable.frame.size.width, 30)];
    searchContainerView.layer.masksToBounds=YES;
    searchContainerView.clipsToBounds=YES;
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView=searchContainerView;
    self.searchController.searchBar.layer.masksToBounds=YES;
    self.searchController.searchBar.clipsToBounds=YES;
    [searchContainerView addSubview:self.searchController.searchBar];
    [self.searchController.searchBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 30)];//Make sure that your header view and searchcontroller size is same
}
```

Then add these delegate methods

```
- (void)didPresentSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController{
    [searchController.searchBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 30)];
}
- (void)didDismissSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController{
    [searchController.searchBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 30)];
}
```

That worked for me, I hope you will make it work

Comment: I am able to get this code to adjust the width of the search bar, but my search bar still jumps out of the top of my table view and goes to the top edge of the screen. If I try to move it down in didPresentSearchController: then it will start to be cut off oddly despite giving it a large height or larger Y position.

Comment: Can you post some of your code, I cannot figure out what is missing.